# Can an Arcane Trickster/Wizard multiclass write down AT spells into its spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, multi-classing, rogue

It is said, AT are half-wizards who know their spells so well they don't need a spellbook to cast them. Wizards can read and write down spells, make Scrolls or copy them.
Can these perfect entities write their own, well-known spells into their spellbook by heart?

My example:

I have a 9AT/1W character.
My AT knows the Sleep spell and my spellbook contains Charm Person.
After I leveled up as AT, I have an option to change one of my spells to another one which is illusion or enchantment.

Can I change Sleep to Charm Person, meanwhile I write Sleep in my spellbook?

In this case, I don't lose any of my spells but I can prepare other, more useful spells as a Wizard and Charm Person will be always "prepared".
I could do the same if I changed the spells anyway and then bought a Sleep scroll somewhere but this is more time-consuming and illogical.

Comment: Related: [Can a multiclass Wizard/Fighter (Eldritch Knight) add EK known spells to the wizard spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123417/33707)

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site or check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Because Eldritch Knights and Arcane Tricksters are basically the same with regards to their spellcasting, I've marked this question as a duplicate of the other (which is no bad thing, since others who want to know about AT/Wizards can now find the other answer via this question). If the other question _doesn't_ answer yours, please let us know (e.g. you can ping me by including @NathanS in a comment) so that we can try to differentiate between these two questions.